# http interceptor with Authentification AND Cache

Tags: angular, http, frontend

For a school project I'm currently building a website. I implemented a Authentification http interceptor which is working well. Every user have a session etc. Problem now is that I want to cache some requests, I looked for tutorials that show how to achieve that. But they only have one http interceptor and not two like I want. How can I implement this second interceptor ?

Comment: Create the second interceptor and add it to the providers like your http interceptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in your `AppModule`:

```
 providers: [,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: InterceptorOne,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: CacheInterceptorTwo,
      multi: true,
    }
  ],
})
```

Basically the above code provides your custom implementation of HTTP_INTERCEPTOR, and by setting the `multi` flag to true it returns an array of instances. As per the angular [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ValueProvider#properties)

> This is useful to allow multiple providers spread across many files to
>   provide configuration information to a common token.

Which is exactly what you need :)